# Access VBA Select SubForm Records Update with Input Tag

Tags: vba, ms-access, dynamic-sql, recordset

I have a main form that has buttons on it, and a subform object set to a dynamic sql statement.  I set up a private sub for the on_exit of the subform object to grab the seltop and selheight.

```
Private mlngSelTop As Long
Private mlngSelheight As Long

Private Sub frmLists_SubResults_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    'GRAB FIRST AND LAST SELECTED RECORDS
    mlngSelTop = Me.frmLists_SubResults.Form.SelTop
    mlngSelheight = Me.frmLists_SubResults.Form.SelHeight
End Sub
```

Then I do 2 cycles through that recordset.  The first checks that the user selected more that 1 record. If they did, I ask them to provide a tag name, so I can tag the selected records with a custom tag name.  I then loop through the recordset again, and for each item, and execute a dynamic sql update statement to update the tag column based on the recordset ID.

This is the routine, which runs on command button click on the main form. I put a comment where the error happens:

```
Private Sub cmdTagList_Click()
    Dim Message, Title, Default, TagListRecs
    Dim w As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim F As Form
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dbu As DAO.Database
    Dim RSu As DAO.Recordset
    Dim usql As String
    Dim fsql As String
    
    Set F = Me.frmLists_SubResults.Form
    Set RS = F.RecordsetClone
    
    ' Move to the first record in the recordset.
    RS.MoveFirst
    
    ' Move to the first selected record.
    RS.Move mlngSelTop - 1
    
    'LOOP THROUGH SUBFORM RECORDSET FROM SELTOP TO SELHEIGHT AND BUILD COUNT
    
    w = 0
    For x = 1 To mlngSelheight
        w = w + 1
        RS.MoveNext
    Next x
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    'CHECK COUNT OF SELECTED RECORDS
    If w < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Please select records from the subform, by selecting 1 record on the left of the row," & vbCrLf & _
                "press the shift key and select the last record to be tagged.", vbCritical, "Must Select Records to Tag"
    
    'MULTIPLE RECORDS WERE SELECTED - DO UPDATES
    Else
        Message = "Please Provide Tag Name:"  ' Set prompt.
        Title = "Provide List Name"    ' Set title.
        Default = "0"    ' Set default..
        TagListRecs = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
        Set RSu = F.RecordsetClone
    
        RSu.MoveFirst
    
        ' Move to the first selected record.
        RSu.Move mlngSelTop - 1
        'CYCLE THROUGH RECORDSET AND RUN UPDATE SQL TO TAG RECORDS SELECTED WITH THE TAG NAME PROVIDED
        For y = 1 To mlngSelheight
     
            usql = "UPDATE tblVFileImport SET CallSheet = '" & TagListRecs & "' WHERE ID = " & RSu![ID]
    
        'THIS IS THE LINE THAT ERRORS - RUN-TIME ERROR 91
            dbu.Execute usql, dbFailOnError
        'THIS IS THE LINE THAT ERRORS - RUN-TIME ERROR 91
        RSu.MoveNext
        Next y
    
        RSu.Close
    
        Set RSu = Nothing
        Set dbu = Nothing
    
        fsql = "SELECT XXX.FIELDS " & _
            "FROM XXX "
        fsql = fsql & "WHERE NZ(XXX.FIELD1,'') <> '' AND XXX.TAGCOL = '" & TagListRecs & "' "
        fsql = fsql & "ORDER BY XXX.FIELD1"
    
        Me.frmLists_SubResults.Form.RecordSource = fsql
        Me.frmLists_SubResults.Form.Requery
    
        Me.lblFilter.Caption = "List tagged for " & TagListRecs & ". Copy List to Excel and Have Fun!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `Set dbu` before attempting `dbu.Execute` ... so that triggers the *"Object variable not set"* error (#91).

Add a line with `Set dbu = CurrentDb` before `For y = 1 To mlngSelheight`

Comment: Wow. I am an idiot and you are a genius! Thank you!